# ¿Como puedo disminuir el tiempo de ejecución de mi consulta?

Tags: mysql, script

Tengo una consulta que permite retornar contratos especificando que: Cuando la fecha mas actual de un amparo de una póliza (que tiene como llave foránea la id de póliza) y esta fecha es menor a la fecha actual arroje el `string 'Alerta'`, y cuando esto no suceda `'No Alerta'`. El problema radica que el tiempo de ejecución para 3 contratos es alrededor de 8,4 segundos. Lo cual es mucho tiempo teniendo en cuenta que es un segmento de un script mayor y la cantidad de contratos que se consulta es mayor a 100.

RELACIONES DE LAS TABLAS UTILIZADAS:
Un contrato puede tener una o más pólizas. Una poliza pertenece a un contrato.
Una póliza puede tener uno o más amparos. Un amparo pertenece a una póliza.

Se muestran las tablas con la información necesaria para la consulta:

```
CONTRATOS  
╔════╦══════════════╦══════════════════╗ 
║ ID ║  numero      ║ fechaSuscripcion ║        
╠════╬══════════════╬══════════════════╣  
║2012║ cps-5-2017   ║ 2017-01-20       ║  
║2027║ cps-20-2017  ║ 2017-01-20       ║  
╚════╩══════════════╩══════════════════╝  

POLIZAS
╔════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║  IDcontrato  ║
╠════╬══════════════╣
║ 29 ║ 2012         ║
║372 ║ 2012         ║
║ 62 ║ 2027         ║
╚════╩══════════════╝

AMPAROS POLIZAS
╔════╦══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ ID ║  IDpoliza    ║ VigenciaHasta ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 81 ║ 29           ║ 2017-08-16    ║
║ 82 ║ 29           ║ 2017-08-16    ║
║ 813║ 372          ║ 2017-09-15    ║
║ 814║ 372          ║ 2017-09-15    ║
║ 160║ 62           ║ 2017-08-20    ║
║ 161║ 62           ║ 2017-08-20    ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

¿Hay alguna forma de optimizar el tiempo de ejecución de esta consulta? El resultado esperado sería el siguiente:

```
╔═════════════╦════════════╗ 
║ numero      ║ alerta     ║        
╠═════════════╬════════════╣  
║ cps-5-2017  ║ 'No Alerta'║  
║ cps-20-2017 ║ 'Alerta'   ║  
╚═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Consulta:

```
Select con.numero,if((Select amp.VigenciaHasta from amparospoliza as amp
                    Where amp.VigenciaHasta = (Select max(amp2.VigenciaHasta) 
                                            from polizas as poli 
                                            INNER JOIN amparospoliza as amp2 ON poli.ID=amp2.IDpoliza
                                            WHere poli.IDcontrato=con.ID)                   
                    group by amp.VigenciaHasta)<CURDATE(),'Alerta','No Alerta') 
from contratos as con 
Where con.fechaSuscripcion >= '2017-01-01' limit 3
```

Comment: tienes muchos select anidados yo lo haria mas o menos de esta forma `Select con.numero, if(amp.VigenciaHasta < CURDATE() , 'Alerta','No Alerta') 
from contratos as con 
INNER JOIN polizas AS poli on poli.IDcontrato=con.ID INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(VigenciaHasta) VigenciaHasta, IDpoliza FROM amparospoliza GROUP BY amparospoliza.IDpoliza ) as amp ON poli.ID=amp.IDpoliza Where con.fechaSuscripcion >= '2017-01-01' limit 3` recuerda que podemos tener errores de redaccion con respecto al codigo

Comment: @JackNavaRow como no escribes una respuesta?

Comment: @lois6b no tengo ciencia cierta de que funcione el query y que sea util

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El query funcionó bien y sin errores, pero no realiza la misma tarea que el query original. Debido a que cuando el contrato tiene dos o mas polizas (que usualmente tienen mas de un amparo) retorna el mismo contrato uno 'con alerta' y otro con 'no alerta'. La idea es que se compare el amparo con la fecha mas reciente con la fecha actual y arrojar la alerta.

Comment: Por favor, agrega un set de datos, el resultado esperado, y los explain de las tablas. Sin saber indices ni contenidos dificil ayudarte...

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Gracias por la observación, soy nuevo publicando en en foro. Ya edité la pregunta, Espero que sea info. suficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal cómo te han comentado, sin los explain de las tablas y sin información de los índices es difícil darte un diagnóstico. Lo único que puedo hacer es reescribir sin tantas subconsultas a nivel de campos las cual normalmente tiene un impacto negativo en el rendimiento.

```
SELECT  con.numero,
    (CASE WHEN M.VigenciaHasta < CURDATE() THEN 'Alerta' ELSE 'No Alerta' END)
    FROM contratos AS con 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  poli.IDcontrato,
                MAX(amp2.VigenciaHasta) AS VigenciaHasta
            FROM polizas as poli 
            INNER JOIN amparospoliza AS amp2 
                ON poli.ID=amp2.IDpoliza
                GROUP BY poli.IDcontrato
    ) AS M
    ON M.IDcontrato = con.ID
    WHERE con.fechaSuscripcion >= '2017-01-01' limit 3
```

Básicamente: Armamos una subconsulta a nivel de tabla con la `VigenciaHasta` máxima por cada `poli.IDcontrato` que relacionamos con contratos mediante un `INNER JOIN`. Tener en cuenta si hay `contratos`  que no tengan registros en `polizas` y `amparospoliza` no van a recuperarse, a menos que usemos un `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Solo para salir de dudas, después del else debería estar el 'No alerta' verdad? Voy a revisar la consulta para entenderla mejor ya que mis conocimientos en mysql son bastante básicos. PSD: Modifiqué la pregunta incluyendo información util sobre las tablas. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Si, un copy paste poco inteligente, ahí lo corrijo. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ejecute el query, junto con la corrección sobre el else e hice revisiones aleatorias. Los resultados son los esperados y la velocidad de ejecución disminuyó abismalmente. Muchas gracias.